# Error calling dateadd function

Tags: function, windows-7, vb6, dateadd

Please help me on this. I run the same code on other computer and they return no error. But on my pc this still pops up.

EDIT:

Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Msgbox (DateAdd("d",-1,Date))
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Run-time error '5';
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

BTW. The computer I used is a windows 7 VM.

EDIT 2:

I manage to run the code by editing a parameter but with a wrong output.

Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Msgbox (DateAdd("dddd",-1,Date))
End Sub
```

Output:

```
5/5/2014
```

Comment: you are very much unclear in your requirement, provide more information?

Comment: I would like to but my account limit me on uploading images to make my question more clearer.

Comment: Do you think it the settings of my VM affect the DateAdd function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works without any problems with VB6 on my Windows7 64bit machine:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim datNow As Date
  Dim datYesterday As Date
  datNow = Now
  datYesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, datNow)
  Print "Yesterday = " & CStr(datYesterday)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  MsgBox (DateAdd("d", -1, Now))
End Sub
```

Btw: you can remove the () in the MsgBox call:

```
  MsgBox DateAdd("d", -1, Now)
```

I let those stay in my test to see if that might have caused the problem, but it works with them as well

Are you sure you are using VB6?

You could also try to create an install package on the machine where it works, and then install it on the other machine. If it then works, then there are probably some libs missing

Comment: Hi, yes I am using VB6 SP6, I try to create exe file directly and not pressing ctrl+F5 and it successfully compiled. No errors encounter. But still when I run the code in IDE, error still persist. I think you are right about some libraries that are missing, but I am not sure what file/s is/are missing.

Comment: try to reinstall the VB6 development environment .. first uninstall the VB6 IDE, and then install it again

Answer (score 1):

if you set the VB6.exe run as XP3 mode , uncheck it , then it will be OK.
Even you didn't do above, it will only happn in IDE mode , but not after
compiling as EXE.